90s movie about 2 kids, ghost dog & ghost sheriff dad, comedy
I remember seeing the last half hour or so of this English live action 90s looking TV movie up until 2010 I think, but on a channel that mainly shows older movies. 
Basically we have 2 kids, max age 10-12, brother & sister whose dad was a sheriff with a big white cowboy hat and had a dog too. They were somehow killed by 2 incompetent bandits. The dog was about as big as a Beagle. What happened in the last half hour is this: the 2 bandits had some shack where they were hiding some stolen or counterfeit goods involving chemicals (and paint probably). The boy (probably the girl too but mostly the boy) was constantly seeing the ghost of the dog, which was leading him to various clues. The dog could not talk like in My Ghost Dog (1997) TV movie, which is all Google turns up when I look this up. Instead, the ghost dog could bark, this was useful in scaring the bandits who could not see it (only the kids could). The dog leads them to the bandits' shack where they were making their counterfeit chemical product. The kids first call the cops but the 2 guys trick them into thinking they're legit. After this, the 2 kids literally sit one on top of each other and make it seem like they're the dead sheriff come back to haunt them while the ghost dog also barks for intimidation. They manage to record one bandit admitting to something they've committed, but the other one catches onto the trick. There is a short fight which they win eventually. Cops arrive and arrest the 2. At the end, the ghost dog heads towards their ghost dad, who smiles at them in a last goodbye, then they fade away.
Also worth mentioning is one of the bandits was more susceptible to being scared by the ghost dog and was getting paranoid about this, while the other one was more down to earth & skeptical of this, thinking hey the guy & the dog are dead, you're only hallucinating. The scared one confessed and was tape-recorded. Apart from these 2 deaths, the movie was basically a comedy.

Ok so I membered the dog's name (Marlowe) and with a bit of luck, found it myself. It's Cop Dog (2008).
Wiki plot: Cop Dog is a 2008 American film created by Dog Productions. In the film, Marlowe (Kuma) is inherited by the son (William Brent) of a deceased police officer (Tom Shell). However, the son's family is targeted by thieves who want revenge against the child's father, who arrested them prior to the events of the film. After hitting Marlowe with a truck, the spirit of Marlowe assists Brent and his friend (Cassi Thomson) to uncover his father's secrets and stop the thieves.
Trailer:



